# Выбрать значения из data frame на пересечении строки-столбца

Tags: математика, r

Существует два вектора:

```
a <- c(1,5,9,7)
b <- c(4,7,2,3)
```

**Необходимо выбрать значения, которые находятся на пересечении этих индексов.**

Когда я делаю так:

```
tabl[a,b]
```

То выводяться вся таблица со строками и столбцами которые соответствуют a и b.

**А необходимо чтобы было так:**

```
tabl[1,4]
tabl[5,7]
tabl[9,2]
tabl[7,3]
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попарное применение можно сделать с помощью `mapply` или `Map`.

```
mapply(function(i, j) tabl[i, j], a, b, SIMPLIFY = TRUE)
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Спасибо огромное!